# How do you store html elements (including tags) in a database using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a "div" tag with some text and a "p" tag with the title, I want to store those elements with its contents, including tags in the database, which belong to a user.

What would be the best way to store the "div" with its content and the "p" with its title using PHP and MySQL?

This is something very similar to how to store user's comments with their titles.

Example:

HTML

```
<p name="myTitle">This is my title</p>

<div name="myContent">
    This is a paragraph This is a paragraph 
    This is a paragraph This is a paragraph
</div>
```

Please help.

Comment: ... have you tried using and `INSERT` statement to insert the data into a column in a table?  If not, then what *have* you tried, and what hasn't worked?

Comment: I'm sure that the more important data to store is information about those tags. For example, if this is part of a blog, you don't store the code directly, but the title as one column, the content as another, the author ID , etc.

Comment: My concern here is, how to store tags in php then send to database.

Comment: @Raeki thats correct, maybe I didnt explain very well but if the user has more than one set (div and p tags) lets say 5 sets, then how would it be done?

Comment: may be some special chars  escape that and try insert

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  PHP more or less wouldn't care about tags.  Where is the data coming from?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, so this isn't a great example, but say each div was a paragraph in a blog post. You may have a table for: entryID, content, index. Where entryIDs may repeat multiple times (unlimited amount of paragraphs to a blog entry). I'm not sure if this is clear (not a great example) but yeah

Answer (score 4):

Step 1, connect to the database and tell it what character set we're using.

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=HOSTNAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    ));
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Step 2, insert into your table.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name(p_column, div_column) VALUES(:p, :div)';
try {
    $sh = $db->prepare($sql);
    $sh->execute(array(
        ':p' => $VARIABLE_CONTAINING_P,
        ':div' => $VARIABLE_CONTAINING_DIV,
    ));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Insert failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Now you know how to insert values into your database.  You will note that nothing here has been expressly escaped.  There are two reasons:

1. By [creating a prepared statement](http://php.net/pdo.prepare) and [binding parameters at execute time](http://php.net/pdostatement.execute), we *automatically* prevent nasties inside the HTML from creating a [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
2. You are storing HTML.  There is no reason to encode or otherwise mangle the HTML that you're storing here.  It's HTML.  It's intended to be displayed as HTML, so why destroy it?  However, that doesn't mean it's *safe* HTML.  If it was HTML entered by the user, it might be malicious.  You should use an HTML filter, like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to permit *only* the content you expressly want in there.

Hopefully this meandering and over-reaching answer will come close to being a solution for your vague and under-specified question.  If you can provide more details on exactly what you are trying to accomplish (see: [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/135887)), then I may be able to give you more *useful* details.